# Linking directories with ln -s

Tags: fedora, symlink

I have a directory on a small disk:

/home/me

Here I have another directory with more space:

/data/work/mywork

I did this:

```
ln -s /data/work/mywork /home/me
```

And while in /home/me this:

```
wget htmlToSomeLargeFile
```

I thought SomeLargeFile would go straight to /data/work/mywork

but `ls` shows the opposite

`ls`/`ll` in /home/me shows "SomeLargeFile" and "mywork -> /data/work/mywork"

Comment: What `ls` command did you use and what does it show?

Comment: Was `/home/me` an already existing directory? If so, is there now a symlink `/home/me/mywork`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `ln -s /data/work/mywork /home/me` puts a softlink **inside** the `/home/me` directory.  It does not replace your `/home/me` directory.  Once you create the softlink, you need to `cd mywork` to `wget` files into the linked directory.

Comment: Then what's the point?

Comment: @AWE The point is the thing you expect, but if you have an existing directory of the same name, this surprising behavior occurs.